# PyQt only gives SIGSEGV when running via PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, python-3.5

I'm a bit at a loss. I have a fairly large application that I'm usually running via the command line:

```
python3 scanner.py
```

That runs fine.

But when I run it via PyCharm using the little play button, I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/cherubim/Projects/Argus/scanner.py

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I've set up the configuration using the exact same script, the exact same Python version, with the exact same environment variables (PYTHONPATH, specifically).

Using print-statements (the debug mode gives the SIGSEGV before stopping at any breakpoint) I've traced the error to this line of code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QCoreApplication, QEvent, QUrl, pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QLocale, QTranslator, QLibraryInfo, QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR
```

Somehow, that import seems to give a segfault when running via PyCharm, but not when running it separately via the command line. Normally at this point I'd get gdb to debug where in PyQt the error is occurring. But this doesn't work when running PyCharm via gdb, obviously.

How do I debug this?

I'm running PyCharm 2017.1.1, Python 3.5.2, PyQt 5.8.2 and Qt 5.8.0.

Comment: Make sure that [Python interpreter set in Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) settings is the right version (v3.5.2). Also, [invalidate cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/cleaning-system-cache.html), and finally, separate your imports to know exactly which one is causing the error.

Comment: Are you also sure that you use the same Python interpreter? What is the output of the `which python3` command?

Comment: Yes, the "Configurations..." menu in PyCharm says Python 3.5.2. Running `python3 --version` on the command line also says 3.5.2.

Comment: Clearing the cache of PyCharm had no effect. The segfault occurs at any import from PyQt5 (but again, only in PyCharm).